# Can I use Javascript that typewrites multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a web page that makes it look like an old computer booting up using the "typeWrite" function and add an "_" after the paragraph.
The text will be multiple lines written into a div (like "Checking RAM.... OK"  "Checking CD-ROM....OK" and so on).
I can't make the string go to the next line.
I have tried 
 and \n, and I tried to split the string and join it with \n. I have tried to put in a backslash () where I want the line to end.. No success.
Any ideas??

```
var i = 0;
var txt = 'First line, second line, third line, and more';
var speed = 150;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}


<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<div class="typewriter">
<p id="demo" class="text"></p><span>_</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding a `pre` element around `#demo` and using new lines in the `txt`, like `First line,\n second line`, etc.

Comment: Try adding the `<br>` tag to insert a line break

Answer (score 2):

This is because HTML doesn't generally respect whitespace.  You could try using break tags (`<br>`), but because your text is generated, you could also probably just change the styling for the paragraph.  If you add `white-space: pre` it will respect `\n` characters.

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'First line,\nsecond line,\nthird line,\nand more';
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}
```

```css
#demo {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>

<div class="typewriter">
<p id="demo" class="text"></p><span>_</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add an after tag in css for the underscore

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = 'First line\nsecond line\nthird line, and more\nFirst line\nsecond line\nthird line, and more\nFirst line\nsecond line\nthird line, and more\n';
var speed = 50;

let demo = document.getElementById("demo");
let typewriter = document.getElementsByClassName("typewriter")[0];

function typeWriter() {
  demo.classList.add("writing");
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    typewriter.scrollTop = typewriter.scrollHeight;
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }else{
  demo.classList.remove("writing");
  }

}
```

```css
@keyframes blinking {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
  100% {opacity: 0;}
}

body{
  margin:0;
}

.typewriter{
  width:100vw;
  font-family:Consolas;
  height:30vh;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

button{
  margin-left:10px;
  border:none;
  background:#DDD;
  height:35px;
  width:70px;
}

#demo{
  white-space: pre;
  margin:0;
}

#demo::after{
 content: '_';
 animation:1s blinking infinite step-end;
}

#demo.writing::after{
animation:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="typewriter">
<p id="demo" class="text"></p>
</div>

<button onclick="typeWriter()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue of break tags, which is what the original poster was asking about, but I agree that this would be an improvement to their code.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Is there any way I can make the underscore blink/flash?

Comment: Yes! Add an animation to it! Ill add it to the Snippet

Comment: @JosephMarikle i know i just wanna add this thing to it, if you want you can add the thing with the underscore to your answer and i delete this one